# php_ini settings in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4

I am working on laravel4 . In my website I have added a pluggin to add images , pdf and video from this link 
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html

So I want the user can add large video so I have added in /public/index.php

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1000000M'); 
ini_set('post_max_size', '1000000M'); 
ini_set('max_execution_time ', '1000000'); 
ini_set('max_input_time ', '1000000'); 
set_time_limit(10000);
```

I can't add this code in my htacces file as my server will not allow me and gives the 500 error . So can any one suggest me where i can declare the php_ini settings

Comment: We can chnage all of this options in php_ini file itself. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: I can't  change the php.ini because I don't have the access of php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You will have to contact the people from where you brought your hosting. For shared hosting many companies do not provide these rights to Cpanel. So the only way open is to contact them.